# Log Shipping, secondary server error. Error 5 - Error 3201

Tags: sql, sql-server, log-shipping

I am making the configuration to make a Log Shipping, but when I click ok after filling in all the fields of the necessary configuration, the following error appears:

Restoring backup to secondary database error 5, besides a mistake 3201.

I already have access to both servers, shared folder and sql.

Comment: `error 5, besides a mistake 3201`??? What does the error message really say? An error 3201 in connection with a database restore is often "Cannot open backup device" because the .bak file can't be opened, e.g.: the file/share path is invalid or filesystem/share permissions don't allow it. It's the SQL Server instance that needs access, not your good self.

Comment: SQL Server runs under a separate service username, which is not the same as the one you are using, and needs separate permissions